# Yii and Wordpress Admin Integration

Tags: wordpress, yii

I have integrated Yii and Wordpress which works totally fine with Url management using this article http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/322/integrating-wordpress-and-yii-still-another-approach-using-yii-as-the-router-controller/

Now I want to save my Yii Models from Wordpress, basically I want to access my Yii models from functions.php but I am unable to load the Model directly.

I tried to do this

```
if (is_admin()) {
global $yii,$config;
if (is_null($yii))
{
    $yii = ABSPATH . '../../framework/yii.php';
    $config=ABSPATH. '../protected/config/main.php';
}
require_once($yii);
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
}
```

but it is saying that wp-theme directory is not there...
I want to save the model from yii itself, how to do so ?